# How to set a password to the postgreSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, installation

During installation, the wizard of postgreSQL didn't ask me to specify the password and port number. Now I want to connect to the server but there's no password or port number set ! How to set them?

Comment: The default port is 5432. https://www.dbrnd.com/2018/04/postgresql-how-to-recover-postgres-user-password/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is suitable for you

If you use linux, you can try :

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres # to enter postgres terminal
\password postgres # to change password
\q # To quit
```

---

It the above doesn't work, you can try :

```
sudo -u postgres psql
\password postgres
\q
```

or if not work, try simply `\password`

---

It the above approach doesn't work yet, you can try to change the `/etc/postgresql/<your-version>/main/pg_hba.conf`

from `local   all             all                                     peer`

to `local   all             all                                     md5`

or `local   all             all                                     trust`

try one by one if need, and after each change restart postgres daemon

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

After each change(and restart), try the first or second approach to change your password

Don't forget to change this back to password or md5 or peer or your original value

---

As mentioned in the comment, the default port is 5432 (and it is very likely that your port is the default)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after uninstalling and deleting all data, then reinstalling.